# What would be the sample number if two variables have different number of samples?

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, pearson-r, degrees-of-freedom

While correlating two variables, which have different number of samples in each, how can I find the df?

Eg. Sample-A has 35 observations, Sample-B has 22 observations,

How to calculate df (N)-2?

Whether 35-2 or 22-2?

Comment: To calculate correlation you need data that occur as ordered pairs (2=tuples). Consequently, they won't have different sample sizes.

Comment: I analyzed in MS excel. If few observations are missing in between in an array also, the correlation function gives a result. I hope those missing values would be omitted (cross checked). So I should consider smaller number of observations to calculate DF (22-2).

Comment: Unless you are a real expert -- and even then -- Excel is a truly awful platform for such calculations because, among other things, it will silently remove data or treat blanks as zeros, *etc.*  You are therefore *much* better off protecting yourself by cleaning the data and asking Excel to compute with pairs of *non-missing* data.  Then you will know what df to use.